# Extracting only the uppercase strings using Python

Tags: python, regex, string, filtering

**I have the strings:**

```
S1 = "ABC is the text"
I need output as "ABC" only
```

**Another example:**

```
S2="LTE Is Getting Evolved"
output: LTE

InputString =
"ACK ACKnowledgment
ACRRAMN Artificial
ANR123 Automatic NR Relations
124APN Access Point Name
A12RQ Automatic Repeat reQuest
BP Bandwidth Part XZ"

output:

ACK
ACRRAMN
ANR123
NR
124APN
A12RQ
BP
XZ
```

*The case is I need only the UPPER CASE string not that has the Upper Case as a part of the string.*

Comment: What if there are more than one such string in there?

Comment: Do you mean the first upper string? Can you give an additional example which is wrong or not the case you want?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: What should be the output for "LTE123 Is Getting Evolved"?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you please show your code for discussion?

Comment: I tried the 
`import string
s = "ACK ACKnowledgment"
print(s.translate(None,string.ascii_lowercase))`
but getting failed as it is filtering the uppercase letters

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the strings into tokens and then use isupper like this:

```
S1 = 'ABC is the text'

for t in S1.split():
  if t.isupper():
    print(t)
```

Comment: You don't need the .split(), strings are already iterable. Your code still works though

Comment: @JamesMcClay the question implies (although the OP isn't very clear) that they want wholly capitalized words in the string, so you'd have to tokenize it somehow

Comment: @JamesMcClay Strings are indeed iterable character by character but that doesn't really help if my understanding of the OP's question is correct. I quote "The case is I need only the UPPER CASE string not that has the Upper Case as a part of the string"

Answer (score 0):

You can get those tokens with a conditional comprehension using  [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`str.isupper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper):

```
[t for t in S2.split() if t.isupper()]
# ['LTE']
```

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? It is right.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
def get_upper_words_from(s):
    results = []
    for word in s.split(" "):
        if word.isupper():
            results.append(word)
    return results
```

The results is a list of all the found words. If you prefer regex instead:

```py
import re
s = "My string HERE"
pattern = r"\b[A-Z]+\b"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

EDIT: removed the semicolon and simplified condition